# Using an image for the background of a JPanel and JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to use an image I made in photoshop as the background for my GUI.  How do I do that?  also I made some images I want to display in the button backgrounds after the action is performed...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add other components to JFrame with background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960279/add-other-components-to-jframe-with-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the JButton, use this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button Name", new ImageIcon("foo.png");
```

The Panel is a bit more interesting. This is a good method, though:

```
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("foo.png").getImage());
```

Comment: if you want to change the image later. Each Object has a `setBackgroundImage()` method, too.

Comment: `ImagePanel` is not part of the standard JDK, can you provide a link?

Comment: @Jeffrey I was going to put the link but forgot where it was. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewKemnetz you can specify the location using things like `../foo.png` for the above directory, or `images/foo.png` to go into an images folder to find the image. Google how to find paths to files.

Comment: [link] (http://www.wildcrest.com/Software/J2PrinterWorks/documentation/api/com/wildcrest/j2printerworks/ImagePanel.html) is the API for the class. I don't know where the actual library is, but `JPanel` works roughly the same.

Comment: -1 button.icon != button.background or in other words: when setting the icon, the text will _not_ be shown on top of it (as it would with a background image)

Comment: Which package contains the ImagePanel?