# Background Images Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using an image for the background of a JPanel and JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373006/using-an-image-for-the-background-of-a-jpanel-and-jbutton)

Similar question to this one HAVE been asked before, but this is slightly different.  I want to know if anyone knows how to set the BACKGROUND of a JPanel/JFrame in swing.  I need to place buttons and text fields OVER this image eventually.  All the solutions on here so far have been adding the image to a JPanel which doesn't work when I use GridLayout etc.

Comment: @Matthew Kemnetz I vote for closing this question as duplicate too

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes I did.  I implemented it just as you linked there.  The problem is that it adds adds the image to the frame instead of making it the background upon which I can overlay buttons...

Comment: @AndrewThompson I will delete my question but I just don't understand how to adapt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960279/add-other-components-to-jframe-with-background) to make it be the background of a frame...

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to make it work.  This is my first project with swing so its been tough.  But now I have to set the background of the top JPanel to transparent so you can see my Background image.  When I try to set that background image to transparent using gui.setOpaque(false) it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

You may create a custom JPanel by inheriting it which paint the given image as background. Here is the code. Here is an example:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
  private Image img;

  public ImagePanel(String img) {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
  }

  public ImagePanel(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using this code, the image would not fill the panel, and the content would not be painted.  BTW 1) When an `ImagePanel` requires an `Image`, specify an `Image` as the argument to the constructor and stop p*ssing about with `String` arguments (pet hate of mine). 2) The sizes (preferred/max/min) are merely suggestions that may or may not be enforced by the layout. 3) A `JPanel` implements `ImageObserver` so can be used as the argument to `getWidth(ImageObserver)` or `getHeight(ImageObserver)`.  Please consider reading more replies before adding answers on topics on which you are inexperienced.

Comment: @AndrewThompson +1 for being in educative mood :-)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the information. +1 for explaining my mistakes.

Comment: You are very gracious about the matter.  With that kind of common sense, I can imagine myself up-voting some of your answers in the near future, and am looking forward to it.  :)